# Use string interpolation to bind controls from FormGroup to template inside *ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular

What i am trying to do is to add the [formControl] attribute with string interpolation in the input text tag.
  Let me show you the code.

add-team.component.ts

```
constructor(fb:FormBuilder) { 
 this.addTeamForm = fb.group({
  'textTeamName':[null,Validators.required],
  'player1':[null,Validators.required],
  'player2':[null,Validators.required],
  'player3':[null,Validators.required],
  'player4':[null,Validators.required],
  'player5':[null,Validators.required],
  'optionWicketKeeper':false      
});
```

add-team.component.html

```
 <label>Fill Player Names</label>
  <div class = 'row form-group' *ngFor = 'let player of players; let i = index;'>
      <input type='text' [(ngModel)] = 'player.name' [formControl] = 'addTeamForm.controls["player{{i+1}}"]' class ='form-control col' placeholder="{{p}} {{player.index}}">
</div>
```

I need to use string interpolation operator in the value of [formControl] attribute such that it will read the controls (player1, player2, player3, player4, player5) and because I also have used *ngFor (for showing in a loop).
But i am getting error:

```
Error:
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected at column 29 in [addTeamForm.controls["player {{i}}"]] in ng:///AppModule/AddTeamComponent.html@9:57 ("= 'let player of players; let i = index;'>
```

Is there any alternative way where i can use interpolation ({{}}) in *ngFor to use in [formControl] attribute?

Comment: Why would you even want to do this? Like suggested, decide to use **either** template driven or reactive form :)

Answer (score -3):

You can tell angular in other way too. Use following code:

```
<label>Fill Player Names</label>
  <div class = 'row form-group' *ngFor = 'let player of players; let i = index;'>
      <input type='text' [(ngModel)] = 'player.name' formControlName = "player{{i+1}}" class ='form-control col' placeholder="{{p}} {{player.index}}">
</div>
```

Hope it will help. If not working then let me know.

Comment: this wont work as it is; the addTeamForm hasnt been binded anywhere in the template

Comment: So why you created a formGroup object in your ts file. Second important thing it's not my mistake. Not everytime everyone provide full code. It's very obvious and expected thing that you definitely used formGroup directive in your template.
If you are doing something strange then please clear in your question.

Comment: Ask OP, but you are making to many unsafe assumptions. "Its very obvious" isnt really the case. Avoid doing assumptions by leaving questions in the comments.